# Export Orders Data Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, export

Is there any Magento1.x Extension that allows me to export orders specification? I need to create a report with the following data:

- order_id (one order can have more than one product)
- customer_name
- product_sku
- product_name
- quantity
- date

Is there any extension that helps me do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Wyomind Order Export Tool](https://www.wyomind.com/orders-export-tool-magento.html) would do what you want.